# Next app correct ui shown wrong status code in client

Tags: next.js, error-handling, next.js13, react-server-components

When a fetch request within a RSC is made (that returns a 500) and I throw and error within the RSC so that I render an error ui.

In my network tab, I expect to see the status code 500.

Can someone explain why this is not the case.

However if I call `notFound()` from next navigation I do see 404 status code next to the file in the network tab

I have the following files:

- app/page.tsx
- app/error.tsx - "use client"
- layout renders html markup that renders page.tsx as child

Page.tsx

```
export default async function SomePage(props) {
  const id = props.params.id;

  if (!id) notFound();

  // some fetch function to return error wihth statuscode 500
  const { data, error } = await someFetchFunction(id);


  // throwing error shows error.tsx
  if (error) throw new Error("Internal Server Error");

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a Server Component. The error will then show up in the server log not the browser.

If you run it locally from the command line, you should see it there.

Comment: Yes correct it's a server component and I am able to log stuff to the server log.

So when error is thrown inside a react server component, the error object is forwarded to  error.tsx.



The rendered html sent to the client will have a status code 200, it's just inside the error.tsx I can render some jsx that explains to user what kind of an error occurred.

For some reason, I was thinking status code will make it's way to the client.